# The oldest known examples of written Latvian

Tags: history

For my research, i am looking for the oldest known examples of written Latvian. According to Wikipedia it's the translation of a Latvian hymn made by Nikolaus Ramm (1530) with no more info provided, no details, no resources. I assumed that it should be found somewhere. I Googled for it, with no success. I would really appreciate if you could find it for me, or at least provide a confirmation about whether it still exists or has been lost.

Comment: Have a look at this, it says that "they say" Ramm may have translated the hymn: http://www.lituanus.org/2002/02_2_07.htm

Comment: As i understand, he translated German hymns to Latvian. I'm sorry, but how exactly does that help me? I need to find that text. :(

Comment: It follows from that text that the originals didn't survive...

Comment: You mean the part about traders in 1525.? I get that. But there's a mention about Riga Johann Briesmann's Kurtz Ordnung des Kirchendiensts, i guess that it contains Nikolaus Ramm's translation, right? It should be, because year 1530 is also mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latvian_language quote: "The oldest known examples of written Latvian are from a 1530 translation of a hymn made by Nikolaus Ramm, a German pastor in Riga." Let's assume it's there, can you help me find it?

Comment: Velta Ruke-Dravina's "The Standardization Process in Latvian" analyzes the language of these early texts, I suggest you check there.

Comment: 136 pages. Jesus, that will take a while :/ But could turn out to be a useful resource, thanks for that at least.